# deploy OSGI bundle in karaf with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I distribute the OSGI bundle in karaf with jenkins pipelines and Jenkinsfile, automating and scheduling this operation?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pax Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=54263871#content/view/54263871) framework.
Pax exam can be triggered as a part of maven integration tests. Pax exam creates an instance of servicemix/karaf and make it available for installing your own bundles.